# How to define keybinding inside a marked region

Tags: emacs, vi, region

I have a idea to mark regions in emacs easier.

1. I press C-SPC to start.
2. I use a vi style key to extend selection. such as

> ```
> "j" : line down
> "k": line up
> ```

instead of using arrow key or C-n, C-p,  a  singe char is easier to press

1. When finish selecting, I choose a key to do some thing, also use a vi style key

   "c": deactive region, copy region.
   "d" delete region
   "#" comment region
   "space" just leaving without do anything

I know I can use "M-w" "M-k" or something to do it, but I think vi style key is a easier way to do the job.

I search everywhere, but there is no elip package can do such thing.

Can someone  help me to write some functions to do it?  Or give me some suggestions.

I found a nice way to do it, share the solution:

(

```
defvar active-region-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    map)
  )

(define-minor-mode active-region-mode
  "Active Region minor mode."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " Region"
  :keymap active-region-mode-map
  :group 'active-region
  )

(defun active-region-on ()
  (active-region-mode 1))
(defun active-region-off ()
  (active-region-mode -1))
(add-hook 'activate-mark-hook 'active-region-on)
(add-hook 'deactivate-mark-hook 'active-region-off)
```

Now, enjoy it, "active-region-mode-map" map keybinding you like. For example:

```
(define-key active-region-mode-map (kbd "j") 'next-line)
```

Comment: I don't know enough elisp/have enough time to do this myself, but: You can probably rebind j/k/c/d/# from their "self-insertion" code to some custom code to check if the mark is active. If it is, do what you describe, if it isn't, call self-insert.

Comment: I will try it. I think some can write a region-mode-map. Such code can make me easier to define keybinding.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a good idea. Automate that "rebind self-insert" thing and then it's easy.

Comment: The region has more uses than just for commenting, deleting etc. The region restricts the area of operation of many commands. e.g. "C-M-h C-x n n" to narrow to the current function etc. While your project is interesting, I think your productivity with Emacs will improve if you master it's own paradigms rather than graft stuff from vim.

Comment: Thank you! This code is great! I use it for move-text.el, multiple-cursors.el and eval-code-in-region... Really saves me a lot of time to figure out the key-binding stuff, or maybe even a keyboard : ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the [viper-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode).

Comment: I know viper-mode, but my idea is a easier way to do this in emacs. Inside a region, you can use a single key instead of combo key. It is not a edit mode, just like dired mode or ibuffer mode.

Comment: I don't think that this is feasible, unless you're willing to define a whole mode just for this functionality... Single key are by default bound to self-insert and getting around that is a bit tricky, not to mention that it violates the Emacs core keybinding principles :-)

Comment: But in some mode , you can use this kind of key binding. 
Dired mode,  "n" "p" instead of " c-n" "c-p"
Inside a region, you can use such key binding too.
I wish there is a region-mode-map.

Comment: Since the there is no editing in such modes they have clearly bound the keys to something different than self-insert. You could potentially add some advice around mark-region(or whatever it was called). The advice is something like aspect oriented programming - it allows to invoke code around other code. Wich such an advice you could temporarily rebind your keys for the duration of select region and restore the old-bindings afterwards. have a look at defadvice in the Emacs Lisp manual.

Comment: I just solve the problem, you can write a simple minor mode, named as active-region, and write a active-region-mode-map.
with this mode, you can define any keybing in region. Overridng a default key binding is very easy (M-w to something else).

I found the answer in google, but your comment give me good advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: @textpattern: Why don't you write up your solution and submit it as an answer to your question?

Comment: Because it is just too simple.
There is a internal hook named: activate-mark-hook, with this hook, you can define keybinding or do something in region. 
I will update my post, put the answer in it.